# Using NPM package on Meteor's Template

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, momentjs

I've added the `moment` package using `mrt add moment` to format dates/times on the clientside within Meteor's templates. However I seem to be able to use it on the serverside but not within the template helpers.

How can I use `momentjs` within the template helpers?

**server/main.js (Works!)**

```
var moment = Meteor.require('moment');
var t = moment( '2013-11-24 16:18:06' ).format('HH:mm:ss');
console.log(t);
```

**client/main.js (Does not work)**

```
Template.fruits.myTime = function() {
    var moment = Meteor.require('moment');
    var t = moment( '2013-11-24 16:18:06' ).format('HH:mm:ss');
    return t;
}
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I tried using `Npm.require('moment')` which gave an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Npm is not defined`

and `Meteor.require('momemt')` which gave an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'require'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add moment using

```
mrt add moment
```

then it is available directly as function:

```
moment()
```

You can always find out how to use particular package by looking at its package.js file. Take a look at [package.js in moment package](https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment/blob/master/package.js):

```
...
if(api.export) {
  api.export('moment');
}
...
```

I noticed that it is very convenient to use moment by registering global handlebars helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('nice-date', function(date){
    return moment(date).fromNow();
});
```

and using it directly in template:

```
<template name="test">
  {{nice-date createdAt}}  // 5 seconds ago
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Meteor package, you should never need to use `require()`. How did you add Moment? Via the package on Atmosphere (https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/moment) using the command `mrt add moment`?

Per that page, once the package is added you should see a `moment` global variable that you can simply call:

```
var oneMonentPlease = moment();
```

You don't need to put any `require` statements anywhere. The above line should just work.

Since Moment is a client-side library, you don't necessarily need to add it as a Meteor package or Npm module. You could just download http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js and save it in your `/lib` folder. Do that and it will automatically be available to both client and server, and the above line of code will work.